# Проблемы с файлами хостинга

Tags: файлы, файловая-система, hosting

Возникла проблема из неоткуда, после очередного фикса бага у меня полетел весь сайт (хотя на локальном хосте всё показывает нормально). Даже если я удалю все папки по типу css, js и т.д, у меня всё равно они будут отображаться на сайте. Плюсом JS скрипт работает некорректно (хотя на том же локальном хосте всё прекрасно). Почему-то загружаются старые версии CSS и JS которые я давно удалил и отличаются от новых. Ещё не добавляются видео и аудио файлы на сайт (в панеле
они есть)

Comment: Кэш браузера? .